# How to populate HTML drop down with Text File using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now, Basically i want to populate the below select with option group and option check boxes. The text file imports to JS just fine, i'm getting the problem trying to populate the drop down. Here is my HTML:

```js
function LoadTxtFile(p) {
    var AllTxtdata = '';
    var targetFile = p.target.files[0];
    if (targetFile) {
        // Create file reader
    var FileRead = new FileReader();
        FileRead.onload = function (e) {
            if (FileRead.readyState === 2) {

                AllTxtdata = FileRead;
                // Split the results into individual lines
                var lines = FileRead.result.split('\n').map(function (line) {
                    return line.trim();
                });     

                var select = $("#MySelect");
                var optionCounter = 0;
                var currentGroup = "";
                lines.forEach(function (line) {
                    // If line ends it " -" create option group
                    if (line.endsWith(" -")) {
                        currentGroup = line.substring(0, line.length - 2);
                        optionCounter = 0;
                        select.append("<optgroup id'" + currentGroup + "' label='" + currentGroup + "'>");
                        // Else if the line is empty close the option group
                    } else if (line === "") {
                        select.append("</optgroup>");
                        // Else add each of the values to the option group
                    } else {
                        select.append("<option type='checkbox' id='" + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' name'"
                            + (currentGroup + optionCounter) + "' value='"
                            + line + "'>" + line + "</option>");

                           }

                });
            }
        }
        FileRead.readAsText(targetFile);
    }

}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', LoadTxtFile, false);
```

```html
<html>
<body>


     <select name="MySelect" id="MySelect"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? What errors are are you getting in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using `append` incorrectly as you are dealing with partial nodes with the `optgroup`. I would build the html snippet then append it in one go. This would also bring a performance benefit as multiple DOM manipulations can get expensive.

I'd do something like the following.

```
function LoadTxtFile(p) {
    var AllTxtdata = '';
    var htmlString = '';
    //Optional Templates. I find them more readable
    var optGroupTemplate = "<optgroup id='{{currentGroup}}' label='{{currentGroup}}'>";
    var optionTemplate = "<option type='checkbox' id='{{currentGroupCounter}}' name='{{currentGroupCounter}}' value='{{line}}'>{{line}}</option>";
    var targetFile = p.target.files[0];
    if (targetFile) {
        // Create file reader
    var FileRead = new FileReader();
        FileRead.onload = function (e) {
            if (FileRead.readyState === 2) {

                AllTxtdata = FileRead;
                // Split the results into individual lines
                var lines = FileRead.result.split('\n').map(function (line) {
                    return line.trim();
                });     

                var select = $("#MySelect");
                var optionCounter = 0;
                var currentGroup = "";
                lines.forEach(function (line) {
                    // If line ends it " -" create option group
                    if (line.endsWith(" -")) {
                        currentGroup = line.substring(0, line.length - 2);
                        optionCounter = 0;
                        htmlString += optGroupTemplate.replace("{{currentGroup}}", currentGroup);
                        // Else if the line is empty close the option group
                    } else if (line === "") {
                        htmlString +="</optgroup>";
                        // Else add each of the values to the option group
                    } else {
                        //I'm assuming you want to increment optionCounter
                        htmlString += optionTemplate.replace("{{currentGroupCounter}}", currentGroup + optionCounter).replace("{{line}}", line);
                   }

                });

               select.append(htmlString);
            }
        }
        FileRead.readAsText(targetFile);
    }

}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', LoadTxtFile, false);
```

**NOTE** the above is untested and may need some debugging.